# Allow anything through CORS Policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

How can I disable cors? For some reason I wild carded the allowed origins and headers yet my ajax requests still complain that the origin was not allowed by my CORS policy....

My applications controller :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :current_user, :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == :options
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
  private
  # get the user currently logged in
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

end
```

routes:

```
  match "*all" => "application#cors_preflight_check", :constraints => { :method => "OPTIONS" }
  match "/alert" => "alerts#create"
  match "/alerts" => "alerts#get"
  match "/login" => "sessions#create"
  match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy"
  match "/register" => "users#create"
```

Edit---

I also tried:

```
   config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', 
            :headers => :any, 
            :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options]
      end
    end
```

in application.rb

**--edit 2---**

The problem is that Chrome Extensions may not support CORS I think. How can I fetch information bypassing CORS? How should I respond to the preflight check?

Comment: Not "disable CORS" but effectively have no policy? I can't seem to respond to any request.

Comment: Do you use this on localhost ?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I've your same requirements on a public API for which I used rails-api.

I've also set header in a before filter. It looks like this:

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
```

It seems you missed the Access-Control-Request-Method header.

Comment: That's strange. Could you provide more info on the error you get?

Comment: Access-Control-Request-Method is set in request not in response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Request-Method

Answer (score 23):

Have a look at the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) middleware. It will handle CORS headers in a configurable manner.

Comment: We have used rack-cors for months and didn't encoutered any issue so far. Are you sure the problem doesn't reside on the client-side ?

Comment: I think the problem is that Chrome Extensions don't support CORS so maybe the Origin is Null. How can I completely disable CORS and respond to any request including requests with Null origins?

Comment: What Chrome Extension are you using ?

Comment: I am writing a chrome extension that needs to communicate with my Rails backend.

Answer (score 22):

Simply you can add rack-cors gem
https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-cors/versions/0.4.0

1st Step:
add gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
```

and then save and run `bundle install`

2nd Step:
update your config/application.rb file by adding this:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

for more details you can go to https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors
Specailly if you don't use rails 5.

Comment: For me the `.insert_before 0` was important. Before I used `config.middleware.use` and that worked only until I wanted to allow CORS for my `public` directory.

Answer (score 6):

I had issues, especially with Chrome as well. What you did looks essentially like what I did in my application. The only difference is that I am responding with a correct hostnames in my Origin CORS headers and not a wildcard. It seems to me that Chrome is picky with this.

Switching between development and production is a pain, so I wrote this little function which helps me in development mode and also in production mode. All of the following things happen in my `application_controller.rb` unless otherwise noted, it might not be the best solution, but [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) didn't work for me either, I can't remember why.

```
def add_cors_headers
  origin = request.headers["Origin"]
  unless (not origin.nil?) and (origin == "http://localhost" or origin.starts_with? "http://localhost:")
    origin = "https://your.production-site.org"
  end
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
  allow_headers = request.headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
  if allow_headers.nil?
    #shouldn't happen, but better be safe
    allow_headers = 'Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type'
  end
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = allow_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
end
```

And then I have this little thing in my `application_controller.rb` because my site requires a login:

```
before_filter :add_cors_headers
before_filter {authenticate_user! unless request.method == "OPTIONS"}
```

In my `routes.rb` I also have this thing:

```
match '*path', :controller => 'application', :action => 'empty', :constraints => {:method => "OPTIONS"}
```

and this method looks like this:

```
def empty
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: Just to close the circle. This whole CORS mess only happens when your hitting your production back-end from a localhost application, right?
None of this will happen when everything is in production?

Comment: Only if backend and webapp are hosted under the same URL. If they are hosted under two different URLs entirely, then this will happen in production as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem before where it turned out to be the web brower (chrome in my case) that was the issue.

If you are using chrome, try launching it so:

For Windows:

1) Create a shortcut to Chrome on your desktop.  Right-click on the shortcut and choose Properties, then switch to “Shortcut” tab.

2) In the “Target” field, append the following:  –args –disable-web-security

For Mac, Open a terminal window and run this from command-line:
open ~/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ –args –disable-web-security

Above info from:

http://documentumcookbook.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/disable-cross-domain-javascript-security-in-chrome-for-development/

Comment: Why has this been voted down?  I have had a situation similar to the one described in the question which was resolved by running chrome with web security disabled.  The problem occurs when you are running a development server locally.  Obviously you wouldn't leave chrome running with web security disabled always.

Comment: this shouldn't be voted down since he explains the situation correctly :)

Comment: I did not do the vote-down, but from the answer it is not clear this a solution merely for development purposes. While this might solve the problem locally, one cannot expect your web visitors/extension users to do this. So I would clarify that in the answer.

Comment: No vote-down here either, but it used to be that the first instance of chrome run with a given flag caused all other instances to run the same way.  Something to be *very* wary of.  It's all too easy to forget and do some impromptu surfing.

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered with this issue in my rails application in production. A lot of answers here gave me hints and helped me to finally come to an answer that worked fine for me.

I am running Nginx and it was simple enough to just modify the *my_app.conf* file (where *my_app* is your app name). You can find this file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

If you do not have `location / {}` already you can just add it under `server {}`, then add `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';` under `location / {}`.

The final format should look something like this:

```
server {
    server_name ...;
    listen ...;
    root ...;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `OPTIONS` requests?

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for a CORS policy to allow everything/anything.

Here's what I used:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try configuration at /config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put, :patch], credentials: true
  end
end
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the dev should add the 'rack-cors' in the Gemfile

Answer (score -4):

Use VSC or any other editor that has Live server, it will give you a proxy that will allow you to use GET or FETCH