# CORS issue with PhoneGap Angular app and Rails

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting started with PhoneGap, using yeoman, bower and grunt setup with Angular. I'm trying to get a response from my Rails API and always get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.`

I've tried what feels like every solution in the book, but can't get this working.

Here's the necessary code:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  before_filter :set_cors_headers
  before_filter :cors_preflight

  def set_cors_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = AppConfig.client['origin']
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "3628800"
  end

  def cors_preflight
    head(:ok) if request.method == :options
  end
end
```

In my app_config.yml file:

```
defaults: &defaults
  client:
    origin: http://localhost:9000

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

I'm loading this in an initializer, app_config.rb:

```
require 'ostruct'
require 'yaml'

config = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'app_config.yml')) || {}
AppConfig = OpenStruct.new(config[Rails.env] || {})
```

I tried using the Rack CORS gem as well, and have this in my application.rb:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using Rails 4.1.

Comment: It looked like [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19211100/646543) ran into the same issue you did (using rails+angular, ran into a cors issue, tried setting headers/rack-cors) and discovered that the issue was actually a bug in their rails controller. I'm not very familiar with rails, so idk if that's the case here, but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: I messed around with my controller a bit, and actually, I believe you're right. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

To use CORS within Angular, we need to tell Angular that we’re using CORS. We use the .config()
method on our Angular app module to set two options.
First, we need to tell Angular to use the XDomain, and we must remove the X-Requested-With header
from all of our requests.

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .config(function($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
       delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers
        .common['X-Requested-With'];
});
```

Now we’re ready to make CORS requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were ever able to resolve this, but PhoneGap should whitelist all domains out of the box - check your config.xml... Now, if you're using a server with 'Live Reload' (like Ionic/Steroids/etc), it seems that there is an issue where the live reload server modifies your config.xml in a way that removes that whitelisting of * at runtime...

Check out this thread for more details if this is still causing you pains - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/89

Throughout the thread, you will see multiple workarounds.. For me, just modifying my development server for CORS has proven easiest - as this shouldn't be a production issue as live reload will not be used and so the whitelisting in config.xml should address any CORS problems.