# SSL Termination and CORs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, apache, cors

So I have two applications on seperate servers. One is a frontend machine and one is a backend api. We are using SSL which we are terminating at the load balancer.

My problem is that when the frontend (https://frontend.example.com) makes calls to the backend (https://api.example.com)

I get an issue with CORS. It complains about origins not matching (one being http and one https). This happens even with the Allow-Origin header set to *

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the the following header:

```
headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
```

Here's a relevant question:
[Allow anything through CORS Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858178/allow-anything-through-cors-policy)

Comment: Thanks! Shall give it a go.