# How to enable CORS in Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, cors

I'm just about to pull my hair out... I've been trying to enable CORS in this Rails app since the morning and it just doesn't work. I've tried [this](http://www.yihangho.com/rails-cross-origin-resource-sharing/), using  [Rack Cors Gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858178/allow-anything-through-cors-policy) and this [post](http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428) all without success.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's my js:

```
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      if ('withCredentials' in req) {
            // req.open('GET', "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos", true);
            req.open('GET', "http://www.postcoder.lc/postcodes/" + value, true);
            // Just like regular ol' XHR
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState === 4) {
                    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                        // JSON.parse(req.responseText) etc.
                        console.log(req.responseText);
                    } else {
                        // Handle error case
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send();
        }
```

When I try this url (from an external client): https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos that works ok, I'm assuming the problem is with my Rails API. Am I wrong?

**EDIT: Currently I have this in my controller:**

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

# For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.
def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

def cors_preflight_check
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
end
```

Comment: I've tried and it didn't work. I've even used the example app and still no luck

Comment: you ever got this to work? I have a angular front-end making the call and I've tried all the solutions as well. The rack cors gem doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should use [rack cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

It provides a nice DSL, to use in your `config/application.rb`, instead of the messy header work and before filters.

A very permissive would be as follows, but of course, you'll have to tailor it a bit.

```
use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end  
end
```

Comment: Do you mean `config/application.rb` ?

Comment: I dont know what `it didnt work` means :) I use it in my app and its just fine. Do you have a bit more information?

Comment: Ok, it is working on Chrome now. I think the problem was the kind of permissions. Interestingly it doesn't work on FF nor Safari. I guess it has nothing to do with Rails but the JS side of it?

Comment: yeah maybe, try to use this client side: https://github.com/mapbox/corslite/ its meant to be cross browsers unfortunately its just for GET requests.

Comment: Could you please explain "but of course, you'll have to tailor it a bit"? Why is it important and how should we do it?

Comment: I have a similar set up, but have specified a list of allowable origins, but continue runninig  into this error: `cross origin resource sharing error: preflightInvalidAllowCredentials`.  I'm checking the request and see that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the respons header matches `Origin` in the request header.

Any insight?

Answer (score 21):

**Rack::Cors** provides support for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

**Steps to enable rackcors :**

1. Add this gem to your **Gemfile**:

   gem 'rack-cors'
2. Add the code below to **config/application.rb**

**If you are using Rails 3/4:**

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => :any
  end
end
```

**If you are using Rails 5:**

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice explainatation!!! It's work and worth for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Add this to Gemfile: `gem 'rack-cors'` then `bundle install`
2. Create a new file `/config/initializers/cors.rb`
3. Inside the file place the following:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :patch, :put]
  end
end
```

That's it!

FYI the instructions came directly from [here](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors#rack-cors-middleware-)

Comment: I am using: `resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any`