# Rails: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in RoR. I have search everywhere in this site and I could not find an answer to my question.

I tried to create api in Ruby on Rails without view. Basically, I successful in do method get and post to create new data.

My problem now I'm getting `no routes match` error for update and delete. Below is my code for posts controller:

```
def update
  @post = Post.where(id: params[:id], user_id: session[:user_id]).first
  if @post.update_attribute(:description, params[:description])
    render json: @post
  else
    render json: {error: 'Process not completed'}
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.where(id: params[:id], user_id: session[:user_id]).first
  if @post.destroy
    render json: {status: 'Successful'}
  else
    render json: {status: 'Your cannot delete this data'}
  end
end
```

and below is my code for routes

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    get 'users/request_token', to: 'users#request_token'
    resources :users
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

I know this is basic code for you guys. But I hope there's someone can help new people like me to improve in RoR.

Below is view for my error
[image]

Comment: What is the url you are calling?

Comment: Post the views where you are getting error and the error as well

Comment: localhost:3000/api/v1/posts?token=333 sir @Rohit

Comment: I have updated my question sir. Thanks for your response @DeepakMahakale

Comment: can you please check the name of your controller and file name

Comment: It should be `Api::V1::PostsController` and file name should be `api/v1/posts_controller.rb`

Comment: How are you trying to access those routes? Maybe you need to enable CORS. eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751115/how-to-enable-cors-in-rails-4-app

Comment: Guys ! i figured it out ! thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While deleting a post you need to pass a id along with the url

example: localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/:id?token=xyz

you can check your routes using the rake routes command

I hope this helps

Comment: This also answered my question perfectly ! thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You have to call
"http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/333" for delete post with method "DELETE",
and for edit/update post "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts/333" with method "PUT".

Answer (score 0):

Your calling route must me like **/api/v1/posts/:post_id** and in case of update it must be **PUT** type and in case of delete it must be of **DELETE** type request. Please give it a try and let me know if it helps.