# Rails - Allow localhost in CORS settings only in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-cors

I'm configuring CORS settings for my rails server - I want to be able to test my backend when I run it locally, using a frontend on localhost.

But, to my understanding, CORS is an important security mechanism against CSRF(?), so when the app goes to production, I want the backend to only allow the origin of the live website. Like so:

```rb
if development:
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3000', 'localhost:3001', 'https://my-app.com'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end

if production:
  allow do
    origins 'https://my-app.com'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

I understand that it's quite a stretch to have an unknown user run a hostile app on localhost and not knowing what they're doing, but still, rather safe than sorry I'd say.

How would I go about this? And why is this not documented prominently on the Github page of Rack::CORS? I have a feeling there's something I'm missing. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Rails 5 or older you can handle the configuration when you are injecting the Rack::CORS middleware into the stack:

```
# config/initializers/cors.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    if Rails.env.development?
      origins 'localhost:3000', 'localhost:3001', 'https://my-app.com'
    else
      origins 'https://my-app.com'
    end

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Since your Rails application is bootstrapped when initializers are loaded you can determine the environment through `Rails.env`. If you want to avoid hardcoding you could use an environmental variable.

Comment: CORS and CSP do different things. CORS is about foreign sites loading content from yours. CSP is about your site loading foreign content.

Comment: @HariKaramSingh you're correct. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Max, what can you do if the server is running less than rails 5?

Comment: @jamesemanon for Rails 6 or newer your need https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Comment: @Vassilis I have less than version 5 - what do I do for that?

Comment: @jamesemanon you can use the gem... see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751115/how-to-enable-cors-in-rails-4-app