# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource: angular and rails

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cors

I am working on an example rails api/angular app. I am using both `devise` for rails, and `angular-devise` on the front end. the problem right now is i am getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error when I try to authenticate.

at the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858178/allow-anything-through-cors-policy) i have added this to my `application_controller`

```
    before_filter :add_cors_headers

     def add_cors_headers
       origin = request.headers["Origin"]
       unless (not origin.nil?) and (origin == "http://localhost" or origin.starts_with? "http://localhost:")
         origin = "http://api.marketplaceapi.dev"
       end
       headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
       headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'
       allow_headers = request.headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
       if allow_headers.nil?
         #shouldn't happen, but better be safe
         allow_headers = 'Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type'
       end
       headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = allow_headers
       headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
       headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
     end
```

and this to routes.rb

```
    match '*path', :controller => 'application', :action => 'empty', :constraints => {:method => "OPTIONS"}
```

in my angular app, in my app.js, I have this defined;

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider, AuthProvider, SERVER) {

    $routeProvider
     ...

      AuthProvider.registerPath(SERVER.url + '/users/sign_up.json');
      AuthProvider.registerMethod('GET');
      AuthProvider.resourceName('user');
  });
```

and my AuthCtrl

```
angular.module('mpfeApp')
.controller('AuthCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    '$location',
    'Auth',
    function register($scope, $location, $log, Auth) {
     var credentials = {
         email: 'email@mail.com',
         password: 'password1',
         passwordConfirmation: 'password1'
     };
     var config = {
         headers: {
             'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET'
         }
     };


     Auth.register(credentials, config).then(function(registeredUser) {
         console.log(registeredUser); 
     }, function(error) {
         console.log('error:' + error);
     });

     $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function(event, user) {
         console.log('from devise:new-registration event');
         console.log(user);
     });
    } 
]);
```

when I go to the `register.html` page in my angular app, this is the `console.log` output

```
OPTIONS: http://api.marketplaceapi.dev/users/sign_up.json
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.marketplaceapi.dev/users/sign_up.json. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

does anyone have any tips for dealing with CORS in rails & angular? right now I am guessing the problem is coming from the de-coupled nature of this project. i was thinking about just putting them in the same repo, but that seems to defeat the whole premise of using rails as the api layer.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think adding 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' in allow_header may solve your problem which is you wrote on rails side. so it will be like  allow_headers = 'Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type, X-HTTP-Method-Override'

Comment: @krish that was it. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think adding 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' in allow_header may solve your problem which is you wrote on rails side. so it will be like
 `allow_headers = 'Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type, X-HTTP-Method-Override'`

Comment: Late to the party, but where are you adding this?