# Rails: Edit form sends to post route instead of patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-url

After I submit my edit form it routes to  [POST] "/users/1/moves/1/inventory_lists/2"
Instead of my route:
user_move_inventory_list_path
PATCH
/users/:user_id/moves/:move_id/inventory_lists/:id(.:format)
inventory_lists#update

```
<%= form_for(@list, url: user_move_inventory_list_url(@user, @move), method: :patch) do |f| %>
<h3>Edit your list by updating Items</h3>
<p>Any items not in your inventory list will incure additional fees</p>
<% @list.items.each do |item| %>
    <%= f.fields_for item, Item.find_by(id: item.id) do |item_attributes| %>
        <div>
            <%= item_attributes.label :name, "Item Name:"%>
            <%= item_attributes.text_field :name, 'name' => "inventory_list[][item][name]" %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= item_attributes.label :room, "Room Item Belongs to:" %>
            <%= item_attributes.text_field :room, 'name' => "inventory_list[][item][room]" %>
        </div>
        <div>
            <%= item_attributes.label :weight, "Item Weight:" %>
            <%= item_attributes.number_field :weight, 'name' => "inventory_list[][item][weight]" %>
        </div>
        <br><br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<h3>Add Items</h3>
<div id="row1" class="row">
        <%= f.fields_for :item, Item.new do |item_attributes| %>
                <div>
                    <%= item_attributes.label :name, "Item Name:" %>
                    <%= item_attributes.text_field :name %>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%= item_attributes.label :room, "Room Item Belongs to:" %>
                    <%= item_attributes.text_field :room %>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <%= item_attributes.label :weight, "Item Weight:" %>
                    <%= item_attributes.number_field :weight %>
                </div>
        <% end %>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Another Item" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="Remove Item" />
</div>


<%= f.submit 'Update List' %>
```

<% end %>

Comment: I added `config.middleware.use(Rack::MethodOverride)` to ~/config/application.rb but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I had a similar problem and didn't fully understand why, but managed to get it working, I wrote what I looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74663860/5783745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey – one thing I can see here is that you have `user_move_inventory_list_url` instead of the more advisable `user_move_inventory_list_path` especially for internal use cases. This is likely where your issue stems from.

You should almost always use the `_path` variant unless you are providing links for external use cases, maybe a reference to a page on your website from a shared twitter URL, or a newsletter URL you are sending via mail, etc.

Rails should automatically be including a hidden `html` field to override the HTTP method.

You can read some more here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark

Comment: Hey I tried using  _path  and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `<form class="edit_inventory_list" id="edit_inventory_list_2" action="/users/1/moves/1/inventory_lists/2" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">`

Comment: Were you able to solve it? @A-laz